# The hotkey for copying line up/down is inserting a cursor up/down

Tags: visual-studio-code

It is doing the same thing as the shortcut of inserting the cursor above or bellow the current line.

If I change the hotkey for a different key combination then it works.

How to use the default combination?

I'm on Windows 11.

I tried a different combination. It works, but I'd rather use the default.
A different keyboard made no difference.

Comment: 1) what's your multi-cursor modifier? what if you toggle it? 2) What do you see when you [troubleshoot your keybindings](//github.com/microsoft/vscode/wiki/Keybinding-Issues)? Please paste the relevant parts of what you see into a code block in your question post. Include also the top section of the file opened by running `Developer: Inspect Key Mappings` in the command palette and all following text that is related to the keys of interest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized my portable VS Code was outdated.

After updating it, the hotkey works as intended.